# How do I check if a tokenizer/model is already saved

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using HuggingFace Transformers with PyTorch. My modus operandi is to download a pre-trained model and save it in a local project folder.

While doing so, I can see that .bin file is saved locally, which stands for the model. However, I am also downloading and saving a tokenizer, for which I cannot see any associated file.

So, how do I check if a tokenizer is saved locally before downloading? Secondly, apart from the usual `os.path.isfile(...)` check, is there any other better way to prioritize local copy usage from a given location before downloading?

Comment: How did you manage to download  the tokenizer? generally speaking tokenizers in hugging face are saved whether as single json, or a json (vocabulary) + a text file (merges)

Comment: The json file just contains the config file for the tokenizer including the path where the tokenizer is saved. We can do an isfile() check there

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Are you talking about the transformers cache or do you specify the folder with `save_pretrained()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this code in the past for this purpose. You can adapt it to your setting.

```
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer
import urllib
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

def download_vocab_files_for_tokenizer(tokenizer, model_type, output_path, vocab_exist_bool=False):
    vocab_files_map = tokenizer.pretrained_vocab_files_map
    vocab_files = {}
    for resource in vocab_files_map.keys():
        download_location = vocab_files_map[resource][model_type]
        f_path = os.path.join(output_path, os.path.basename(download_location))
        if vocab_exist_bool != True:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_location, f_path)
        vocab_files[resource] = f_path
    return vocab_files

model_type = 'bert-base-uncased'
#initialized tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_type)
#will do this part later

#retrieve vocab file if it's not there
output_path = os.getcwd()+'/vocab_files/'
vocab_file_name = 'bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt'
vocab_exist_bool = os.path.exists(output_path + vocab_file_name)

#get vocab files
vocab_files = download_vocab_files_for_tokenizer(tokenizer, model_type, output_path, vocab_exist_bool=vocab_exist_bool)
```